# Eclipse export .jar file won't run

Tags: java, eclipse

This question is different because this is using Eclipse and Java not Xcode.
I wrote a program using Java EE from Eclipse and when I export it as a .jar file, it won't run. There are no errors thrown when I export it. There are no build nor compile errors and I have JRE up to date. It told me to check my Mac Console and this is the error stated:

```html
error 19:56:00.206708 -0600 QuickLookUIHelper Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
error 19:56:00.236882 -0600 Finder Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
error 19:56:00.370470 -0600 Jar Launcher Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. Try to launch it over the terminal with `java -jar PATH_TO_JAR`